# Data Imputation in Pandas Dataframe column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-science

I have 2 tables which I am merging( Left Join) based on common column but other column does not have exact column values and hence some of the column values are blank. I want to fill the missing value with closest tenth . for example I have these two dataframes:

```
d = {'col1': [1.31, 2.22,3.33,4.44,5.55,6.66], 'col2': ['010100', '010101','101011','110000','114000','120000']}
df1=pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

```
d2 = {'col2': ['010100', '010102','010144','114218','121212','166110'],'col4': ['a','b','c','d','e','f']}
df2=pd.DataFrame(data=d2)
```

```
# df1
   col1    col2
0  1.31  010100
1  2.22  010101
2  3.33  101011
3  4.44  110000
4  5.55  114000
5  6.66  120000

# df2
     col2 col4
0  010100    a
1  010102    b
2  010144    c
3  114218    d
4  121212    e
5  166110    f
```

After left merging on col2,
I get:

```
df1.merge(df2,how='left',on='col2')

    col1      col2  col4
0   1.31    010100     a
1   2.22    010101   NaN
2   3.33    101011   NaN
3   4.44    111100   NaN
4   5.55    114100   NaN
5   6.66    166100   NaN
```

Vs what I want, for for all values where NaN, my col2 value firstly converts to closest 10 and then matches in col2 of table 1 if there is a match, place col4 accordingly, if not then closest 100, then closest thousand, ten thousand..

Ideally my answer should be:

```
    col1      col2  col4
0   1.31    010100     a
1   2.22    010101     a
2   3.33    101011     f
3   4.44    111100     d
4   5.55    114100     d
5   6.66    166100     f
```

Please help me in coding this

Comment: I tried to reproduce your merge but got something else. Please recheck that this is actually what you get from your code.

Comment: Thanks for checking, I have got the same merge as I mentioned which is basically matching exact number and then putting col4 value, else putting NaN.